# Take into consideration the values of multiple columns based on availability for ORDER BY in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have 10 price categories.

I have coded everything so that the correct price gets displayed in the price field according to availability. That part works perfectly.

But I don't know how to set the ORDER BY in the query so that all the price fields get into consideration before being sorted.

I have these fields:

```
'price1`, 'price2`, 'price3`, 'price4`, 'price5`, 'price6`, 'price7`, 'price8`, 'price9`, 'price10`
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY `price1`;
```

This works when there's only fields from price1 being displayed. however if there's a mixed result of price1 and other price fields, it still only takes price1 into consideration.

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY `price1`, `price2`, `price3`, `price4`, `price5`, `price6`, `price7`, `price8`, `price9`, `price10`;
```

which failed obviously.

How can I utilize ORDER BY for all these fields at the same time?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Logically if you think how is it possible to sort multiple fields and get the result you want ?

Comment: @ajay I'm super new to MySQL, so I really don't know what syntax is used to do this, but 'logically', I think there should be a function so that all these 10 fields are joined together and treated as one so that when the ORDER BY 'joined function' is called, all of them are sorted correctly. but since programming only works by the allowed syntax, I really don't have any actual idea as to how to do this, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY GREATEST(`price1`, `price2`, `price3`, `price4`, `price5`,`price6`,`price7`, `price8`, `price9`, `price10`) DESC
```

The above should order from the greatest value found in any of the "price" columns all the way down to the smallest value of the row's greatest column.

Say you have a table

```
 == Table structure for table test

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|id|int(11)|No|
|price1|int(11)|No|
|price2|int(11)|No|
|price3|int(11)|No|
== Dumping data for table test

|1|10|20|10
|2|30|10|10
|3|100|20|10
|4|10|10|60
```

The query

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY GREATEST(`price1`, `price2`, `price3`) DESC
```

Will output

```
== Dumping data for table test

|3|100|20|10
|4|10|10|60
|2|30|10|10
|1|10|20|10
```

Comment: It didn't work, the sorting was different but in no way ordered by the price DESC or ASC, it was rather random

Comment: @ClaudioDelgado What order you want it in? There is also LEAST()

Comment: sorted from lowest to greatest, but using the above code all the numbers where out of order. the order was: 75, 120, 25, 250, 85

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood

`SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY GREATEST(`price1`, `price2`, `price3`, `price4`, `price5`,`price6`,`price7`, `price8`, `price9`, `price10`) DESC`

Should order by the largest price found in any price column to the smallest price

Comment: No matter how I try, it doesn't sort it with that code. it just shows it without any specific order.

Comment: I get it now, your code combines the values of all columns in each result. It does do that when I put it in my code as well. I was just using it in the wrong place. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can union all fields and order like this:

```
select price1 from vehicles WHERE to='$to' union all 
select price2 from vehicles WHERE to='$to' union all 
select price3 from vehicles WHERE to='$to' union all 
select price4 from vehicles WHERE to='$to' union all 
select price5 from vehicles WHERE to='$to'
order by price1
```

Comment: So my query should look like this?

select price1 from vehicles union all; 
select price2 from vehicles union all;
select price3 from vehicles union all; 
select price4 from vehicles union all;
select price5 from vehicles union all; SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY `price1`;

Comment: you must put where condition in all select

Comment: this might sound very very stupid because I don't even know what's happening in the code after tinkering with it for the last 10 mins, but where does your updated code go to in relation to my original code of SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `to`='$to' ORDER BY `price1`; ?

Does it replace it? or do I add it to that? I know I'm very stupid to ask this but I really have no idea.

Comment: I have added your code to the beginning of my own select * from vehicles code, and the error is: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns